# Equilibrium position finding with DSM

Tags: finite-element, iterative-method, computational-geometry

I've coded a framework that can be used to simulate the dynamic behavior of a system discretized by particles (nodes) that are connected by spring-damper elements. However, I want to compare it to a method that directly solves the equilibrium position of such a discretized system.
I've identified the Direct Stiffness Method (DSM) as an option, and I've been trying to implement this with the use of Sympy. The end goal would be to have a functionality that solves for any amount of particles that are connected to 1-3 other particles in 3d space.
To practice, I've been working on a simplified problem in 2d space, which can be seen in the drawing. Nodes 1 and 3 are fixed, while node 2 is deflected in the positive x direction due to a drag force caused by a wind flow in the positive x direction. The value of this drag force is normally a function of the spring elements' length and orientation w.r.t the wind flow but can be simplified in this specific problem.

[image]

The code that I've written is included below, but the value for ux2 is not the same as I get from my simulation. For reference, this code results in a value of 0.215, while the simulation settles around 0.27. I'm pretty certain the simulation is correct, as the output is already validated for a range of problems.
Concluding:

1. I'm wondering if and where the error(s) in my code is.
2. Are there other methods that would be useful to solve this kind of problem?
3. Is using the Sympy library to solve this set of equations the way to go?

```
import sympy as sp

    k = input.params["k"]       #
    n = input.params["n"]
    cd = input.params["c_d_bridle"]
    d = input.params["d_bridle"]
    rho = input.params["rho"]
    vw = input.params["v_w"]
    l0 = input.params["l0"]
    l = input.params["L"]

    ux1, uy1 = sp.symbols("ux1 uy1")
    ux2, uy2 = sp.symbols("ux2 uy2")
    ux3, uy3 = sp.symbols("ux3 uy3")

    # f = 0.5*0.5*rho*cd*(l0-uy1)*d*np.linalg.norm(vw)**2 + 0.5*0.5*rho*cd*(l0+uy1)*d*np.linalg.norm(vw)**2
    f = 0.5*rho*cd*l0*d*np.linalg.norm(vw)**2

    F = sp.Matrix([0, 0, f, 0, 0, 0])
    U = sp.Matrix([ux1, uy1, ux2, uy2, ux3, uy3])

    t1 = sp.atan((l0 + uy2) / ux2)
    t2 = pi - sp.atan((l0 - uy2) / ux2)

    K1 = k*sp.Matrix([[sp.cos(t1)*sp.cos(t1), sp.sin(t1)*sp.cos(t1), -sp.cos(t1)*sp.cos(t1), -sp.sin(t1)*sp.cos(t1)],
                      [sp.sin(t1)*sp.cos(t1), sp.sin(t1)*sp.sin(t1), -sp.sin(t1)*sp.cos(t1), -sp.sin(t1)*sp.sin(t1)],
                      [-sp.cos(t1)*sp.cos(t1), -sp.sin(t1)*sp.cos(t1), sp.cos(t1)*sp.cos(t1), sp.sin(t1)*sp.cos(t1)],
                      [-sp.sin(t1)*sp.cos(t1), -sp.sin(t1)*sp.sin(t1), sp.sin(t1)*sp.cos(t1), sp.sin(t1)*sp.sin(t1)]])

    K2 = k*sp.Matrix([[sp.cos(t2)*sp.cos(t2), sp.sin(t2)*sp.cos(t2), -sp.cos(t2)*sp.cos(t2), -sp.sin(t2)*sp.cos(t2)],
                      [sp.sin(t2)*sp.cos(t2), sp.sin(t2)*sp.sin(t2), -sp.sin(t2)*sp.cos(t2), -sp.sin(t2)*sp.sin(t2)],
                      [-sp.cos(t2)*sp.cos(t2), -sp.sin(t2)*sp.cos(t2), sp.cos(t2)*sp.cos(t2), sp.sin(t2)*sp.cos(t2)],
                      [-sp.sin(t2)*sp.cos(t2), -sp.sin(t2)*sp.sin(t2), sp.sin(t2)*sp.cos(t2), sp.sin(t2)*sp.sin(t2)]])

    K = sp.Matrix(zeros(n*2, n*2))      # 2d evaluation for now
    K[0:4, 0:4] += K1
    K[2:, 2:] += K2

    # K = K.col_insert(6, F)
    # print(K)
    U = sp.Matrix([ux2, uy2])
    F = sp.Matrix([f, 0])
    K = K[2:4, 2:4]
    soe = K*U - F
    x = (0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0)

    u = (ux1, uy1, ux2, uy2, ux3, uy3)
    soe = (soe[0], soe[1], ux1, uy1, ux3, uy3)

    x = sp.solvers.solvers.nsolve(soe, u, x)
```

Comment: One of the challenges you're going to run into is that these sorts of problems do not have a unique equilibrium solution. For example, in the case you show, the third object could also be to the left of the first two, with both springs compressed to compensate the pushing force of the wind. If you have many bodies connected by springs, you're going to end up with a *lot* of local minima.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you, I hadn't thought about that yet. I forgot to mention that the springs in question can only resist tensile forces, not compressive forces. They also only exert a spring force on connected nodes if their length is greater than a set rest length _l0_. At the very least I need to think about how to include these conditions into the equations.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Also wouldn't this pose less of a problem if you already know a vector _x0_ that is very close to the solution that you're looking for?

Comment: Any decent method will converge from a starting point to an equilibrium position. This is *often*, but *not always* the nearest equilibrium point if you start close to one.